# How to Create a Video from a BufferedImage List?

Tags: java, video, bufferedimage

I'm trying to create a Simple Recording Software, so i Created a  `List<BufferedImage>` for Storing the Frames, so how do i convert this in a Video? Most of the Stuff that i found is About Xuggler(That is very dead) and i also want a method that allows me to add Audio to the Video

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this question belongs on another site in the Stack Exchange network (https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i didn't get any responses so after a pretty long time searching i solved it with ffmpeg